# How to show validation errors for each element of a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am modifying the blog of the [guide](http://www.guiasrails.es/getting_started.html) that I have just finished.
What I want now is to show if there were errors in validating comments in the same way that I show them when validating articles.

I already established the corresponding restrictions in the model, and in fact works, because when you want to comment with values that violate the restriction, the system does not save the comment, but the user does not know why that happens.

- **Articulo** means **an article**
- **Comentar** means **to comment**
- **Comentario** means **a comment**
- **Comentarios** means **comments**

Annex some files:

**/app/controllers/articulos_controller.rb**

```
class ArticulosController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secreto", except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @articulos = Articulo.all
    end

    def show
        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @articulo = Articulo.new
    end

    def edit
        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create

        @articulo = Articulo.new(articulo_params)

        if @articulo.save
            redirect_to @articulo
        else
            render 'new'
        end

    end

    def update

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])

        if @articulo.update(articulo_params)
            redirect_to @articulo
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
        @articulo.destroy

        redirect_to articulos_path

    end

    private

    def articulo_params
        params.require(:articulo).permit(:titular, :contenido)
    end

end
```

**/app/controllers/comentarios_controller.rb**

```
class ComentariosController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secreto", only: :destroy

    def new
        articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
        @comentario = articulo.comentarios.build
    end

    def create

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:articulo_id])

        @comentario = @articulo.comentarios.create(comentario_params)

        redirect_to articulo_path(@articulo)

    end

    def destroy

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:articulo_id])

        @comentario = @articulo.comentarios.find(params[:id])
        @comentario.destroy

        redirect_to articulo_path(@articulo)

    end

    private

    def comentario_params
        params.require(:comentario).permit(:comentarista, :contenido)
    end

end
```

**/app/models/articulo.rb**

```
class Articulo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comentarios
    validates :titular, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
    validates :contenido, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
end
```

**/app/models/comentario.rb**

```
class Comentario < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :articulo
    validates :comentarista, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
    validates :contenido, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

**/app/views/articulos/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @articulo do |f| %>

  <% if @articulo.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@articulo.errors.count, "error") %> han impedido que el artículo sea grabado:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @articulo.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :titular %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :titular %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :contenido %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :contenido %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Guardar' %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**/app/views/comentarios/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@articulo, @articulo.comentarios.build]) do |f| %>

  <p>
    Nombre<br>
    <%= f.text_field :comentarista %>
  </p>

  <p>
    Comentario<br>
    <%= f.text_area :contenido %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Comentar' %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**How can I be able to show such errors when validating?**

From already thank you very much.

Comment: you already have the answer in you `/app/views/articulos/_form.html.erb` template, take a look there and check how errors are being displayed.

Comment: Not sure about your question, do you want to send a custom message if a validation fails??

Comment: @fanta  But in **/app/views/articulos/_form.html.erb** I have `<%= form_for @articulo do |f| %>`, then in **/app/views/comentarios/_form.html.erb** I have `<%= form_for([@articulo, @articulo.comentarios.build]) do |f| %>`. They are not the same, I try to adapt it and it does not work.

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla Validating an article will display error messages if it does not meet any restrictions. What I want is to do the same but with every comment that is going to be made for some article.

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39907143/6780663

Answer (score 0):

You should create an error messages partial  **app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb** like so:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>
    <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %> han impedido que el 
      artículo sea grabado: # change artículo to the appropriate word 
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And render the error messages partial inside your articles and comments forms:
**/views/comentarios/_form.html.erb** and
**/views/articulos/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

This is the **DRY** way and it'll work with both articles and comments or any object.

Also, change your comments controller's `create` action to this as it redirects to the article show page instead of showing the errors:

```
def create
  @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:articulo_id])
  @comentario = @articulo.comentarios.create(comentario_params)
  if @comentario.save
    redirect_to articulo_path(@articulo)
  end
end
```

Comment: No, it does not work. Error messages for comments are not displayed.

Comment: I have already solved it on my own. Anyway, thanks for your contribution.